# how to convert html into dynatable or datatable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

my php page returns html table data, i need it to convert into either datatable or dynatable, i tried including required files (javascripts and css) into page where php will return the table and in javascript function i used

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').dynatable();
 });
 </script>
```

It returns html table only, no dynatable features or paging.

i have also tried datatables but not working

Comment: did you include dynatable.js?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `datatable.js` and you can do the function:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#myTable').datatable();
 });
```